# Django REST Framework - Serializer don't see field

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

I want create User, which hold Foreign Key to his Country.
Obviously I want to make it required field.

But when I send POST request without 'country' field, DRF Serializer doesn't throw an error.

Nowhere in the code have I allowed the field to be empty, it's the same as the rest.

I took a step further, and in the `create()` method of my `ModelViewSet` I decided to print `serializer.validated_data`

```py
class UserViewSet(ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = UserSerializer
    queryset = User.objects.all()
    permission_classes = []

    def create(self, request, format=None):
        serializer = self.get_serializer(data=request.data)

        if serializer.is_valid():
            print(serializer.data)
```

I send following POST request:

[image]

And my `serializer.validated_data` value was:

```
OrderedDict([('password', 'test1231112'), ('first_name', 'Jarosław'), ('last_name', 'Psikuta'), ('phone', '2999111331'), ('email', 'rweww@gmail.css'), ('description', 'fajny uzytkownik'), ('address', 'Mieszka 3/4'), ('date_of_birth', datetime.date(1997, 10, 13))])
```

I realised that serializer just don't see my `country` field.

I already write some code to check if my `country` field exist:

```py
country_code = request.data.get('country', None)
if not country_code:
        return Response({'country': 'This field is required'}, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

but I know that's wrong approach. It's additional code, and actually serializer should do that work for me.

Here You have rest of my code:

serializers.py

```py
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = '__all__'
        read_only_fields = ('id', 'last_login', 'is_superuser', 'is_staff', 'is_active','date_joined', 'groups', 'user_permissions')
        extra_kwargs = {
            'password': {'write_only': True}
        }
        depth = 1

    def create(self, validated_data):
        password = validated_data.pop('password')
        user = User(**validated_data)
        user.set_password(password)
        user.save()
        return user
```

models.py

```py
class User(AbstractUser):
    EMPLOYEE_TYPES = [
        ('R', 'Regular'),
        ('S', 'Specialist')
    ]
    username_validator = None
    username = None
    first_name = models.CharField(_('first name'), max_length=30)
    last_name = models.CharField(_('last name'), max_length=150)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=15, unique=True)
    employee_type = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=EMPLOYEE_TYPES, default='R')
    email = models.EmailField(_('email address'), unique=True, max_length=255)
    description = models.CharField(blank=True, max_length=500, default='')
    address = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    date_of_birth = models.DateField(null=True)
    country = models.ForeignKey(Country, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='users')

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['first_name', 'last_name', 'date_of_birth', 'address', 'phone', 'country']
```

Comment: Did you  inspect your serializer? https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#inspecting-a-modelserializer . Also you should declare country field on it and debug how it behaves.

Answer (score 0):

I deleted `depth = 1` from serializer Metaclass and it works.